RISK The Battle for Medieval England Ambiguous Card
First time playing Risk: The Battle for Medieval England and we encountered a power card that is pretty powerful but also very confusing.  Its a power card that once flipped over must be played immediately and it says:
"Lose 3 Troops From Each Territory In the North."
My opponent flipped it and said we all have to lose 3 troops. I was confused because it was his card so I was thinking just his territories. Does everyone lose 3 troops?
I would have written this card as All Territories in the North Lose 3 Troops.
